# Why won't my sidepanel float right at the top of a div?

Tags: css

My sidepanel doesn't float right properly. It acts (for some reason) as if there's a top margin, it refuses to align next to the page title.

I'm also attempting to make it responsive using `<aside>`

It should be here:

[image: Arrow pointing to where the sidepanel should be]

My main content sits in a `max-width:1050px`, the `rowSidepanel` should make a column of `width:60%`, I assumed the `sidebar` would too make a column of `width:27%; float:right;` all within that `pageArea`.

I've inspected element and tried to force `top:0;` etc but it is still not behaving itself.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? .

**HTML**

```
 <div id="pageArea">
    <div class="colPad">
      <div class="rowSidepanel"> 
      <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="main content" -->
        <div class="breadCrumb"> <a href="/">Home</a> <span style="font: Georgia;"> > </span> Repertoire</div>
        <h1>Repertoire</h1>
        <p class="introPara">Intro</p>
        <p>Main content....</p>
        <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> 
       </div>
      <aside id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidepanelArea"> Sidepanel </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearBoth"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
   #pageArea {
        max-width: 1050px;
        margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
        padding: 134px 0px 0px 0px;
        display: block;
        background-image:url("/images/common/centered-page-bg.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 0% 12%;    
        min-height: 667px;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    .colPad {
        padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    }
    .rowSidepanel {
        width: 60%; 
    }

    aside {
        float: right;
        padding: 1%;
        width: 27%;
        margin: 0% 0px 20px 0px;
        background-color:#000;
        color: white;
        opacity: 0.7;
        filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    }
    @media all and (max-width : 799px) {

        #sidebar {
            width: 99%;
            padding: 1% 0px 0px 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            border-top: 3px solid #dc1b20;
             background-color: #FFF;
             color: black;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to add the "HTML5 tag to your question due to the use of the "<aside>" tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your .rowSidepanel is displayed block and no matter of his width he is assigned to be across all screen. Just make him float: left;

```
.rowSidepanel {
width: 60%;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your #breadcrumb, repertoire header, and paragraph element are all block elements and are thus taking up the entire width of the browser (and pushing down your sidebar).

You should group those other elements into a container div of their own and flow that left. Apply background colors to both divs (the one floated left and the one floated right) to visualize what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the div order, #rowSidepanel before #sidebar.

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqosu

Comment: Thanks! This does work, but then when the media query kicks in, it is positioned above the main column, whereas I need it below. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: NP...try the float fixes above.